# Why is ondemand not available as a governor for cpu frequency scaling?

Tags: linux, cpu, x86

Consider the following:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors 
performance powersave
$ cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep -i ondemand
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_DEVFREQ_GOV_SIMPLE_ONDEMAND=m
```

I do not understand why `ondemand` is not an available governor. Where else do I need to look and what do I need to do to enable `ondemand`?

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: @TimothyMartin `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1241 v3 @ 3.50GHz`

Comment: I asked about the processor because of this:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_governors.  I believe the answer from @don_crissti is correct.

Comment: From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt, it seems that using powersave with the intel_pstate driver is similar to using ondemand.